# Fibonacci in NASM - seg fault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, fibonacci

We have to code in Assembly which is as you may know hard. Or professor didnt give us any information how to code or link properly. We had to learn it by ourselves. Tomorrow I have to hand in my work.
The aim is to print the n.th Fibonacci number to the console.

```
section .data
    fmt: db "fib=%d",10,0

section .text
extern _printf
global _main, fib

_main:
    mov eax, 10     ; e.g. n=10
    mov ebx, 1      ; we know f_0 and f_1
    sub eax, ebx    ; thats why n--
    push eax        ; push n
    push 0      ; f_0 = 0 
    push 1      ; f_1 = 1

    call fib

    push eax        ; in eax the result is stored
    push fmt
    call _printf

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1      ; exit(0)
    int 0x80    


fib:
    mov ecx, eax
    pop esi
    calc:
    pop ebx
    pop edx
    add ebx, edx
    mov eax, ebx
    push edx
    push ebx
    sub ecx, 1
    cmp ecx, 0
    jne calc
    push esi
    ret
```

After struggling with the linker I finally managed to assemble and link my program. But it doesn't work - I get a segmentation fault everytime.

**Edit:**
corrected code - I get some text on the console, but sadly no correct number it always displays "fib=1" and again seg fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
push 0      ; f_0 = 0 
push 1      ; f_1 = 1

call fib
```

then

```
fib:
    mov ecx, eax
    calc:
    pop ebx
    pop edx
```

You can't do that - the call instruction will push the return address on the stack, and that's the first thing you'll be popping off in fib.

Comment: so saving the values via pop in the first line and restore via push in the last line (before ret) should work? Any recommendations which register to choose for saving?

Comment: yes, that would work if somewhat unconventional - the most common way is to set up a stack frame, as Gunnar suggests, and to read arguments from the stack into registers. Scratch registers are normally, EAX, ECX, and EDX - the rest usually have to be preserved when you return to the outer-most calling scope. Note however that these conventions are O/S-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find Assembly hard, rather I found it simple and straight forward.  If your teacher does not teach you correctly, it would do you good to search the Internet for information.  Years ago when most of us started, there was not that much information so we used trial and error to learn.

I suggest you start simple and learn about the stack.  Use this as a working example:

```
 extern printf
    section .data
    msg:    db "Your sum is %d",10 ,0

    section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        push    20
        push    2
        push    6
        call    AddEm

        push    eax
        push    msg
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4 * 2  ; printf is C calling convention, we have to adjust stack

        mov     ebx, 0
        mov     eax, 1      ; exit(0)
        int     0x80    

    AddEm:
        push    ebp     ; set up a stack frame
        mov     ebp, esp    ; we could just use esp but we won't

        mov     eax, [ebp + 8]  ; 1st param - 6
        add     eax, [ebp + 12] ; 2nd param - 2
        add     eax, [ebp + 16] ; 3rd param - 20

        mov     esp, ebp    ; restore the stack
        pop     ebp
        ret     4 * 3       ; passed 3 params, clean up stack
```

And this how I Assembled, linked and the output.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: great example, I'll take a look at it after class. I will hand in my defective version now, I lost too much time resolving linker-errors like: "unresolved reference", "unrecognized format" (when using 64bit as object-file output format)